# Javascript Selenium - For some reason my code won't click or navigate on a google page in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, selenium, internet-explorer

I have a bit of a sticky problem with javascript's version of selenium for internet explorer.

I have been trying to do a simple test:

step 1 - open up internet explorer.
step 2 - click the search bar (name is q in the CSS).
step 3 - enter wikipedia in the search bar.
step 4 - press enter to search for wikipedia.

In python and in other browsers this is easy. For some reason in internet explorer it is proving challenging. I have looked at various responses on this site.

Some have called for the search bar to be clicked before entering any data. Others have stated that a wait condition needs to be added. I have done both (please see my code below). If you guys can replicate the issue and help me resolve it I would be very grateful.

Code version 1 which was my simplified version:

```
        async function example (){let driver = new Builder().forBrowser("internet explorer").build();
        driver.get("http://google.com").then(function(){
            driver.wait(elementIsEnabled(By.name("q")),20).findElement(webdriver.By.name("q")).click().then(function(){
                driver.wait(elementIsVisible(By.name("q"))).findElement(webdriver.By.name("q")).sendKeys("Selenium", Key.ENTER);
            })
        });
     }
example ();
```

Code version 2 is more verbose and was my attempt at diagnosing the issue. As you can see I was not successful...

```
async function callOne(){
     await console.log("page complete");}
async function callTwo(){
        await console.log("click complete");}
async function callThree(){
        await console.log("navigation complete");}

let driver = new Builder()
        .usingServer()
        .forBrowser("internet explorer")
        .build();

async function example() {
    try {
    await driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.wait(elementIsVisible(By.name("q")), 20).then(callOne)
    (await driver.findElement(By.name('q'))).click().then
        (callTwo).then(async function(){
            await driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys('wikipedia',Key.RETURN);
        }).then(callThree);   
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("issue with the code")
        ;await driver.quit();
    }
    finally{
        await driver.quit();
    }
}
example();
```

Please see my dependencies:

- IE driver version = IEDriverServer_x64_3.150.1
- IDE = Visual studio code
- Internet Explorer version = 1909
- OS = Windows 10
- Selenium webdriver version in use by Node.js = ^4.0.0-alpha.8

Please see the package.json in use:

```
{
  "name": "webdriver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "selenium example project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "this newbie",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what errors you are getting in the console while running the index.js file? It can help us to get any idea about the issue.

Comment: For some reason, no errors are thrown in the console log or in the network. The only think you can see is the google page. It does time out after a while and throws an error based on that but that's about it.
This is why I think this may be a timing issue or an issue with my code where when executing it stops abruptly.